# Using "has been" in "An application of ABC has been to"

Tags: grammar

I found, in some writings such [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S007668790026059X) and [this](https://www.medicalresearch.nsw.gov.au/app/uploads/2018/05/AU-RED-essentials-for-hre.pdf), the following grammar constructs:

> An application of ABC has been to **[something]**

And:

> An application of ABC has been to **[do something]**

Before, I didn't see any sentences using either of those grammar constructs. The most similar one I found is this (from Oxford Learner's Dictionary):

> [T]he application of new technology to teaching.

And it doesn't have "has been" after "application of ABC".

I did a further investigation and also haven't found any grammar structure that inserts "has been" after "application of ABC". Here's is one [source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/application) for that.

Of course, I don't have problem of understanding the meaning of those two constructs, but really are they considered correct by native speakers?

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer ***One** application of ABC has been [for doing XYZ]*, but apparently [I'm in a minority on that point.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=One+application+of+this+approach%2CAn+application+of+this+approach&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) But I'm not surte exactly what you're asking. Are you just bothered about using Present Perfect rather than Simple Present *One application of ABC **is** [for doing XYZ]*?

Comment: First reference - "Stop the clock before an HREC application has been to a full HREC meeting,
unless the application has been withdrawn. " In a summary text box of do's and don'ts. Please provide the actual sentences and some surrounding text for context in your question. And properly cite the usage, don't just provide a link. This is required on this sort of question. The ABC versions don't really help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, the sentence is:

> A related application has been to use the pGEX plasmids to construct a complementary DNA (cDNA) expression library, which was then probed with DNA or protein probes to identify novel DNA-binding or protein-binding domains

In this case, the "to" just marks the infinitive; it's not a preposition modifying "application." They are equating the application with using the pGEX plasmids. It's a rather odd construction.

In your second example, the full sentence is:

> **Don't:** Stop the clock before an HREC application has been to a full HREC meeting,
> unless the application has been withdrawn.

This whole sentence is rather confusing. The idea seems to be that you shouldn't stop the "clock" timing the application's progress until the application has been discussed and evaluated at a meeting. I suspect that they forgot to put the word "brought" before "to."